# embedded images wrong position (in Kivy RstDocument.source) when converting docx to rst using pandoc

Tags: kivy, pandoc, restructuredtext

I convert a word docx document, containing an image, to rst using the following pandoc command:

```
pandoc -s dsrtest2.docx --extract-media=C:\Container\ -t rst -o dtest2rst.txt
```

The image file is stored nicely in the Container. But the viewer (Kivy RstDocument.source property) shows the image at the bottom of the file. See rst contents:

===================
    This is just a test
    ===================

```
***ProcessView***

The sample text that is inserted in the English version of

-  Word 2007

-  Word 2010 appears resembles the following :

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

|image0|

1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ¶

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps
over the lazy dog.

| *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ¶
  *
| The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps
  over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ¶

Notice that the sample text in other language versions of Word 2007 or
Word 2010 does not have the same meaning as the text that is mentioned
earlier in this section. 

.. |image0| image:: C:\Container\/media/image1.png
   :width: 1.68750in
   :height: 6.34375in
```

When I copy manually the image filepath to the |image0| placeholder, the rst viewer (Kivy RstDocument.source property) shows the image in the correct position.

How could I position the document file reference automatically to the placeholder?

Comment: Seems to be not implemented :-/

Comment: OK. Too bad. Where can I find what directives have been implemented?

Comment: The [rst.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/rst.py) may be your best source. It shouldn't be really hard to implement those changes as e.g. tables are translated into `GridLayout`s if I'm right.